# If Dropdown Selected, push into one array, otherwise, push into a different one

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im programming an app, and i want to push something in a Array, if a Item of the Dropdown is selected, if its not, then it should push it into another Array.
Heres some Code:

**html.js**

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
  <div class="input-label">
    Muscle
  </div>
  <select ng-model="selOption">
    <option>Chest</option>
    <option>Biceps</option>
    <option>Back</option>
    <option>Stomach</option>
    <option>Legs</option>
    <option>Triceps</option>
    <option>Shoulders</option>
    <option>Traps</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.selOption = "Chest";

$scope.createEx = function(){
  if($selOption = "Chest")
  {
    $scope.chestEx.push({title:...., reps:....});
    console.log("Test");
  };
};
```

Comment: Is it now working?  Because you do need to change $selOption = "Chest" to $selOption == "Chest"

Comment: Yep, thank you very much xD

Comment: Also, what is $selOption?  Is this your actual code?

Comment: i used this so the dropdown is default set to "Chest"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ionic-framework but in angular code and html need to change.
need to use `value="someVlue"` in your **option** tag and compare like `if($scope.selOption === "Chest")` instead of `if($selOption = "Chest")`

html:

```
<select ng-model="selOption"> <!--if you want to call on change value then use ng-change="createEx()"-->
     <option value="Chest">Chest</option>
     <option value="Biceps">Biceps</option>
     <option value="Back">Back</option>
     <option value="Stomach">Stomach</option>
     <option value="Legs">Legs</option>
     <option value="Triceps">Triceps</option>
     <option value="Shoulders">Shoulders</option>
     <option value="Traps">Traps</option>
 </select>
```

and controller code:

```
$scope.selOption = "Chest";

$scope.createEx = function() {
   if($scope.selOption === "Chest"){
      $scope.chestEx.push({title:...., reps:....});
      console.log("Test");
   }
   else {// as you need}
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be $scope.selOption == "Chest"?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the ng-change directive and repeat an array of options like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/kdb9ed7f/

**Controller**

```
function Controller($scope) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.myOptions = [];
      vm.options = [
        'Chest',
        'Biceps',
        'Back',
        'Stomach',
        'Legs',
        'Triceps',
        'Shoulders',
        'Traps'
      ];

      vm.checkOption = checkOption;

      function checkOption() {
        if (vm.options[vm.selOption] == 'Chest') {
          vm.myOptions.push({
            name: 'Chest'
          });
          vm.selOption = null;
        }
      }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    <select ng-model="ctrl.selOption" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in ctrl.options" ng-change="ctrl.checkOption()">
      <option>Select One</option>
    </select>
    <hr>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="option in ctrl.myOptions">{{option.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```